# MySQL error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

```
SELECT BookId, Duedate, (SELECT Title FROM Book_Information WHERE BookId = BookId)
FROM Transaction_Information WHERE DueDate <= CURDATE() AND ReturnedDate IS NULL
```

The book id is the foreign key in the transaction_information.
I want to add the Title field from the book information table to the transaction information table

Comment: show your `create table code` of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Transaction_Information.BookId` is the **foreign key** which refers to the corresponding row in `Book_Information` table then a simple `INNER JOIN` would do the job.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
TF.BookId,
TF.Duedate,
BF.Title
FROM Transaction_Information TF
INNER JOIN Book_Information BF
ON TF.BookId = BF.BookId
WHERE TF.DueDate <= CURDATE() AND TF.ReturnedDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select * from Transaction_Information tf,Book_Information bf where tf.BookId = bf.BookID and tf.DueDate <= CURDATE() and tf.ReturneDate is null ;
```